# TomEE maven not getting updated class files

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I have a maven project that I run it using TomEE. I had to modify the source code, then wanted to run the project again on TomEE. The class files got updated, however, TomEE is still running the older version of the project. I noticed that too when I run test in debug it works fine, but when I run TomEE in debug the new source code lines are not recognized during debug. What is the command I should call to make TomEE get the updated class files to run it?

Note that I used: `mvn clean install`, `mvn build` and `mvn clean package`, and to run or debug I used: `mvn tomee:run` and `mvn tomee:debug`

Comment: Did you try to delete the old class files from tomcat?

Comment: @Casper I deleted the target directories. Then with `mvn clean install` and `mvn tomee:run` it worked.